# Does a function $f(x)$ exist for which the Taylor series, taken at any point, converges to $f(x)$ for all $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Does a function $f(x)$ exist for which the Taylor series converges to $f(x)$ for all $x$?  Additional criteria that did not fit well into one sentence: it must be possible for this to hold at *every point* in the domain of $f(x)$--in other words, the Taylor series must converge to $f(x)$ for all $x$, regardless of what $x$ the series $T(x)$ is taken at.

Comment: Yes; examples would be $f(x) = \sin(x)$ and $f(x) = \cos(x)$. And of course, every polynomial. You want to find series with a radius of convergence $R = \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the information; I believe this to be the case, but was not sure.

Comment: What about $0$?.

Comment: This is true for any entire holomorphic function.

Comment: Yeah, I saw "entire functions" defined briefly in a paper--but not strictly enough to be sure that they were what I was looking for.  Thanks :)

Comment: Another easy to see example are all polynomials.